# How can I view complete zsh history?

Tags: zsh, command-history, macos

I am using zsh on MacOS BigSur. If I write `history`, I get the last 15 commands. How can I view the complete history?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`history` in zsh is the same as `fc -l`. `fc -l` is defined as

> fc -l [ -LI ] [ -nrdfEiD ] [ -t timefmt ] [ -m match ]
> [ old=new ... ] [ first [ last ] ]
>
> [...]
>
> If first is not specified, it will be set to -1 (the most recent event), or to -16 if the -l flag is given

(cf. [the docs](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html#Shell-Builtin-Commands)). This clears up why you only get 15 entries: `history` without any arguments is the same as `fc -l -16 -1`.

So to view the complete history, you can use `history 0` or, equivalently, `fc -l 0`.

Answer (score 1):

You can find out where your history file is located like this:

```
$ echo $HISTFILE
```

If this does not return anything, you do not have a `HISTFILE` configued.

If it does, you can take a look at its contents with a pager of your choice.

Comment: it returned this /Users/serax/.zsh_sessions/BDA4CA4B-F7E8-471F-84AB-47881887034D.historynew . So i open the directory in terminal and did `ls` many files appeared. I found 1 file with`.historynew` as extension, 1 `_expiration_check_timestamp` file, and then half of the rest had random characters folowed by`.history` and the other half random characters followed by `.session`. Now, which of these files is the history? If i open the one ending with `historynew` i see just one command that i used some time ago.

Comment: This depends on how your shell is configured. Take a look at the `zsh` configuration files, like `~/.zshrc` and those in `/etc/zsh/`

Comment: and what should I look at in those files? what should i change?The values must be default as i have never changed such settings

Comment: Try seeing what files have a command you _know_ should be in it (but not a common one hat would be in many files)? For example, I use host aliases for machines on my home network, and I know I rarely remote access the machine aliased "jupiter", so I could `grep "ssh jupiter" .*hist* *hist*`. This will only help narrow down where to look, though. You may also want to read the zsh's documentation on how it's history mechanism works, and how you can customize it. (I personally am unfamiliar with it...)